# HTTPS NSURLConnection not working

Tags: ios, https, ios9

I have a website that has traffic on both HTTP and HTTPS.

I develop an app (iOS 9) that call some of these URLs, but when I changed from HTTP to HTTPS I got the following error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

I have already disabled the ATS, because I have a facebook integration and it was complaining.

Here is my piece of code that makes the call, and handles the result:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myRestWebService?test=Y"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *myUrlData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                           returningResponse:&response
                                                       error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myUrlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

As you can see, it is a synchronous call.

The certificate is signed by Go Daddy, so it is trusted, and works well on a browser.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say, "I have already disabled the ATS, because I have a facebook integration and it was complaining," how did you do that? By allowing certain domains and subdomains or by allowing arbitrary loads?

Comment: Allowing arbitrary loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to Apple and turns out my apache had a problem.
Their answer:

> Configure your server to return its intermediate certificate in the
>   TLS handshake.  If you’re using Apache, you should look at the
>   SSLCertificateChainFile directive.

So I set the intermediate certificate and everything start working.